# How the name Aimad is written in Japanese?

Tags: names

How can I write the name Aimad in Japanese?

Aimad (عماد) is an Arabic name which means 頼みの綱 in Japanese and "mainstay" in English, written Aimad or Imad in French and Emad in English.

It is pronounced [[ʕemæ:d]].

Similarly, مجدو  which is Majdou in French and pronounced [[mædʒdo]].

To listen to the sounds for those two words, you can try this [website](http://www.oddcast.com/home/demos/tts/tts_example.php),
just copy and past the Arabic written for Aimad and Majdou and choose Arabic as the language.

Comment: It gets said every single time a name thread comes up: look for people with the name on wikipedia and check their Japanese pages. For example http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%96%E3%83%89%E3%82%A5%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AC%E3%83%95%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB has Emad (عماد) as イマード. Searching google with "イマード" definitely brings up a lot of Emads and Imads...

Comment: What about majdou ?

Comment: Remember, it's a name... and since the translation is phonetic, it will depend on عماد wants it pronounced. 

For example, the `a` in Marie can be pronounced like a short 'e' or a short 'a' depending on where you're from. So, while some British people would spell it マーリ、Americans might spell it メーリ、while an English speaker with French parents might spell it マリー. So... in this case, is the second syllable drawn out, or is it short like the example in the oddcast.com site? イマード、アイマド　etc.

Answer (score 1):

- アイマッド (Ai-maddo)

  or
- アイマード(Ai-Maado)

Answer (score 0):

アイマド, since there is no other possible consonant ending besides "n."